# yet another sticky footer question

Tags: html, css

I know this has been asked here countless amount of times, I've looked around trying to implement the given solutions.

```
#footer
{
  min-width: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Its the very last div on the page. I'm testing it out here blog.0arrays.com (a default theme for tumblr), but the footer just won't stick to the bottom. It appears in the middle of the page. I can provide the full code if anyone wants to look at it, as it's too long to paste here.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I don't really care if its sticky or not (i.e right at the bottom), I just don't want it to appear in the middle of my text, as you can see on the site.

**EDIT 2:**

I've posted the full code [here (via pastie)](http://pastie.org/1285996), arrrr.... I bet the answer is really simple, this is doing my head in. For some reason, your suggestions are not working.

No one...?

Comment: [Yet another sticky footer answer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+sticky+footer): http://www.cssstickyfooter.com

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ - the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to use

```
`display: table-row;'
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other attributes you've set for #footer, you should also add `bottom:0` to set it's position to be the bottom of the page.

EDIT: You will also need `position:fixed` instead of absolute

Comment: Wont work anyway. The element wont follow when you scroll the page. It will stay put at the same position while you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about keeping the footer at the bottom you just have to remove position: absolute; from #posts.

Comment: none of these things seem to work for me...I think there is something very wrong with my code

Comment: removing position:absolute from posts makes the leftmenu div drop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the footer stick to the bottom of page, use fixed position.

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```